# Remove an item from view inside an adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to remove an item from view when its flag become 4. I tried mObjects.remove(position) and  then notifyDataSetChanged(). but it didn't worked.we tried all the following

```
  if (getItem(position).getFlag().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {


            remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            matcheslistview.setAdapter(adapter);
      also this one
          //  mObjects.remove(position)
          // notifyDataSetChanged();

      and this one
           // mObjects.remove(position);
           //remove(position);
           //mainObjects.remove(position);
           //notifyDataSetChanged();

      and this one
        // Object toRemove = adapter.getItem(position);
        // mObjects.remove(toRemove);
        //  mObjects.clear();
```

and all the time we got    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0.Here is the complete adapter class

```
 private class MatchedDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    private AQuery aQuery;
    private Activity mActivity;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private SessionManager sessionManager;

    private int uflag;
    MyFilter mfilter;
    DatabaseHandler db;
    ArrayList<LikeMatcheddataForListview> mObjects;
    ArrayList<LikeMatcheddataForListview> mainObjects;

    Context context;

    public MatchedDataAdapter(Activity context,
                              ArrayList<LikeMatcheddataForListview> objects,
                              int imageHeigthAndWidth[]) {

        this.mObjects = objects;
        mainObjects = objects;
        //Log.e("size", Integer.toString(mObjects.size()));

        this.mActivity = context;
        try {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        catch (Exception e)

        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        aQuery = new AQuery(context);
        db = new DatabaseHandler(context);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mObjects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public LikeMatcheddataForListview getItem(int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.matchedlistviewitem,
                    null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.userimage);
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.userName);
            holder.lastMasage = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lastmessage);

            holder.imgStatus = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgStatus);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.textview.setText(getItem(position).getUserName());



        if (getItem(position).getFlag().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {


            mObjects.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            matcheslistview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

we want to remove Item with flag 4,we are reading this flag with a service from db and onrecive we call class DisplayContentTask as below

```
 class GetLikeMatchedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        new DisplayContentTask(intent).execute();
    }
}
```

how we can get Item position in order to remove the Item with flag 4...or My be  another approach to remove Item with flag 4 we don't know but appreciate your help on this

```
  class DisplayContentTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Intent intent;

    private Ultilities mUltilities = new Ultilities();
    private List<NameValuePair> getuserparameter;
    private String likedmatchedata, Unmatchedata;
    int match1;
    private LikedMatcheData matcheData;
    private ArrayList<com.appdupe.flamer.pojo.Likes> likesList;
    private LikeMatcheddataForListview matcheddataForListview;
    DatabaseHandler mDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
    private boolean isResponseSuccess = true;
    ArrayList<LikeMatcheddataForListview> tempArray = new         ArrayList<LikeMatcheddataForListview>();


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        AppLog.Log(TAG, "BackgroundTaskForFindLikeMatched onPreExecute  ");


    }

    DisplayContentTask(Intent intent) {
        this.intent = intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {


        try {

            File appDirectory = mUltilities
                    .createAppDirectoy(getResources().getString(
                            R.string.appdirectory));
            AppLog.Log(TAG,
                    "BackgroundTaskForFindLikeMatched   doInBackground appDirectory "
                            + appDirectory);
            File _picDir = new File(appDirectory, getResources().getString(
                    R.string.imagedirematchuserdirectory));

            AppLog.Log(TAG,
                    "BackgroundTaskForFindLikeMatched doInBackground ");

            // getuserparameter = mUltilities.getUserLikedParameter(params);


            likedmatchedata = intent.getStringExtra("GET_MATCHED_RESPONSE");
            //   Unmatchedata = intent.getStringExtra("GET_UNMATCHED_RESPONSE");//hadi

            AppLog.Log(TAG,
                    "BackgroundTaskForFindLikeMatched doInBackground   likedmatchedata "
                            + likedmatchedata);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            matcheData = gson.fromJson(likedmatchedata,
                    LikedMatcheData.class);

            AppLog.Log(TAG,
                    "BackgroundTaskForFindLikeMatched doInBackground   matcheData "
                            + matcheData);

            // "errNum": "51",
            // "errFlag": "0",
            // "errMsg": "Matches found!",

            if (matcheData.getErrFlag() == 0) {

                likesList = matcheData.getLikes();
                AppLog.Log(TAG,
                        "BackgroundTaskForFindLikeMatched doInBackground   likesList "
                                + likesList);
                if (tempArray != null) {
                    tempArray.clear();
                }

                AppLog.Log(TAG,
                        "BackgroundTaskForFindLikeMatched doInBackground   likesList sized "
                                + likesList.size());
                Log.v("Matches", "" + likesList.size());
                match1 = likesList.size();

                for (int i = 0; i < likesList.size(); i++) {
                    Log.d("likelist", likesList.toString());
                    matcheddataForListview = new LikeMatcheddataForListview();
                    String userName = likesList.get(i).getfName();
                    String facebookid = likesList.get(i).getFbId();
                    // Log.i(TAG, "Background facebookid......"+facebookid);
                    String picturl = likesList.get(i).getpPic();
                    int falg = likesList.get(i).getFlag();
               //     if (likesList.get(i).getFlag()==4) {
                //        likesList.remove(getId());
                //    }

                    Log.i("komak10",""+likesList.get(i).getFlag());
                    String latd = likesList.get(i).getLadt();
                    matcheddataForListview.setFacebookid(facebookid);
                    matcheddataForListview.setUserName(userName);
                    matcheddataForListview.setImageUrl(picturl);
                    matcheddataForListview.setFlag("" + falg);
                    matcheddataForListview.setladt(latd);
                    // matcheddataForListview.setFilePath(filePath);
                    File imageFile = mUltilities.createFileInSideDirectory(
                            _picDir, userName + facebookid + ".jpg");
                    // logDebug("BackGroundTaskForUserProfile doInBackground imageFile is profile "+imageFile.isFile());
                    Utility.addBitmapToSdCardFromURL(likesList.get(i)
                            .getpPic().replaceAll(" ", "%20"), imageFile);
                    matcheddataForListview.setFilePath(imageFile
                            .getAbsolutePath());

                    if (!preferences.getString(Constant.FACEBOOK_ID, "")
                            .equals(facebookid)) {
                        tempArray.add(matcheddataForListview);

                    }

                }
                DatabaseHandler mDatabaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(
                        getActivity());
                // SessionManager mSessionManager = new SessionManager(
                // MainActivity.this);
                String userFacebookid = preferences.getString(
                        Constant.FACEBOOK_ID, "");

                //
                boolean isdataiserted = mDatabaseHandler.insertMatchList(
                        tempArray, userFacebookid);

            } else if (matcheData.getErrFlag() == 1) {
                if(tempArray!=null)
                {
                    tempArray.clear();
                }

            } else {
                // do nothing
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            AppLog.handleException(
                    "BackgroundTaskForFindLikeMatched doInBackground Exception ",
                    e);
            // some thing wrong happend
            isResponseSuccess = false;
        }



        return null;
    }
```

Comment: you already call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), it will refresh the adapter so remove this line matcheslistview.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: we tried this one as you can see in commented part in code.but it didn't work.the same error

Comment: @HadiSamadbin you have error on getItem(position).getFlag().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("4")

Comment: no we have error on this:  mObjects.remove(position) or the same codes when try to remove positon the we got tis error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0...if you search this error the answers are calling notifyDataSetChanged  whichi didn't worked.  indramurari  is right check his answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't remove the object in getview, if you have to filter it, filter it before sending out to adapter. May be possible that while creating the child view the 1st cell has tag "4" now the view didn't create(since return was not called) but you are trying to remove its position, so it will definitely give you IndexOutOfBoundsException.

My best solution would be, set the adapter with

```
new ArrayList<LikeMatcheddataForListview>()
```

whenever you start the screen. Once your AsyncTask completes filter out the child with tags "4"(better filter it out in the asynctask only, less task in ui thread) then refresh the adapter, like

```
public void refresh(ArrayList<LikeMatcheddataForListview>() arrObjects){
   objects = arrObjects;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Check it out, it should do the trick

Comment: How we can get item position which its flag is 4 in DisplayContentTask..?

Comment: How does the flag change to 4? Isn't it from the DisplayContentTask?

Comment: we are reading this flag with a service from db and onrecive we call DisplayContentTask .I can get flag in DisplayContentTask but I cant get Item position which its flag is 4 in DisplayContentTask

Comment: What does the method getitem(position) exactly do? I believe the in ArrayList<LikeMatcheddataForListview> this object LikeMatcheddataForListview has a flag which gives 4 or not, so if any object has 4 remove it from the arraylist before populating it on the listview. Rectify me if im wrong about your problem.

Comment: yes you are right and I tried this line of code    if likesList.get(i).getFlag()==4) {    likesList.remove(getId());       }

Comment: yes you are right and I  already tried this line of code if( likesList.get(i).getFlag()==4) { likesList.remove(getId()); } and it didnt work..so this might get me wrong that I needed get item positon.

Comment: How should I remove it from the arraylist before populating it on the listview?

Comment: before populating the data in the list view, can you run a loop to check the flag? do it in a thread, or in the the asynctask whether you are fetching all the data. once everything is done. populate it on the list view

Answer (score 1):

Please try following

**Your code**

```
if (getItem(position).getFlag().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {


            mObjects.remove(position);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            matcheslistview.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

**TO** 
do not set adapter again to list view

```
if (getItem(position).getFlag().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {

           mObjects.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: we tried this one as you can see in commented part in code.but it didn't work.the same error

Comment: @HadiSamadbin what was the error can you please post logcat

Comment: @GanshGudghe this is our logcat error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0

Comment: @GanshGudghe Dear GanshGudghe ur suggestion is now working we are checking all conditions as we are sure we tried this one..maybe android studio didn't consider changes reading from cash...keep in touch I  will accept your answer soon.

Comment: @GanshGudghe Dear  when There is more than one Item in the List then we get java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Invalid index 1, size is 0

Answer (score 1):

This may not be correct approach to remove the item form `listview`.

Whenever your `adapter` data is getting changed then just check if that flag matches your string i.e. "4" in each item and remove the respective item from the list and just call `notifyItemRemoved` with position insted of `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: we are reading this flag with a service from db and onrecive we call class DisplayContentTask extends AsyncTask.so you mean inside DisplayContent classs we should remove item?

Comment: @Hadi Samadbin Yes you can do that in `onPostExecute` of `DisplayContentTask`

Comment: How we can get item position which its flag is 4..as we at not advanced in android could you please help us in coding.If you need Display Content class code I can send you.appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Dear indramurari could u pls helps us more..we dig a bit more and we found notifyItemRemoved works with recyclerview .also we cant get item position out side adapter even with tag.

Comment: @HadiSamadbin what else help you need?

Comment: @ indramurari we cant get item position even with settag in DisplayContentTask..do u have any chat Id ?